# Without a lease, how to establish Maryland residency for driver's license?

Tags: residential-lease, maryland

I have worked/rented in Maryland for 18mo, but the coworker I rent a room from won't give me a lease (and I do not wish to create any problems with him by insisting).

Can I get my driver's license with no lease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maryland MVA](http://www.mva.maryland.gov)'s '[sources of proof](http://www.mva.maryland.gov/drivers/apply/sources-of-proof.htm)' page lists these as proof of Maryland residency; at least two are required.

- Maryland vehicle registration card or title;
- Utility, telephone or cable/satellite TV bill;
- Checking or savings account statement;
- Life insurance card or policy (over 3 years old);
- Property tax bill or receipt;
- Mortgage account or proof of home ownership (Deed, Title, Bill of Sale or Statement from Maryland Assessment and Taxation);
- Residential rental contract (apartment lease or other rental of real property)(current formal contract or agreement between landlord and tenant which includes all signatures);
- First class or priority mail from a federal, state or local government agency to include the contents and envelope, excluding mail from the Administration;
- Copy of federal or MD income tax return filing not more than 18 months old, with proof of filing;
- Installment contract from a bank or other financial institution;
- Sales tax or business license;
- Major credit card and Department/Retail store credit card bills (Wal-Mart, Sears, Lowe's, Exxon, etc);
- Residential service contract (refers to services performed at the address of residence; for example, cable or satellite television, TV repairs, lawn service or exterminator contract);
- Canceled check with imprinted name and address;
- Voter registration card;
- Selective Service Card.

The documents you submit must also satisfy these requirements:

- Must include the applicant's name and residence address.
- May not be from the same business, company or agency.
- Must reflect a current, recent or valid date.

So while a lease is a valid source of proof, as long as you can provide two from the list above then you won't need a copy of your lease to get your license.

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed that list a long time ago and couldn't supply 2 of the documents, but now that you show it to me again, I think I can get the license. I have my paychecks and bank statements, so that should do it!